# Reading in multiple words on a single line as separate variables (C++)

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a text file that has two words next to one another separated by a space. I am trying to read in the words using `>>` but whenever I attempt to do this, it reads in the same word.

```
string word1;
string word2;

ifstream fin;
fin.open("text.txt");

while (!fout.eof())
{
    fin >> word1;
    cout << word1 << endl;
    fin >> word2;
    cout << word2 << endl;
}
```

The first word in the file is the. The second is happy. When I try to output the words, both are the. How should I go about reading in both words as separate variables?

Comment: Perhaps of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941

Comment: Also of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301 Feels weird posting this after the previous comment.

Comment: @user4581301: sorry for the previous comment it was for some other topic

Comment: @KerrekSB Then should I use something like while(getline(fin, word1))? .eof() is what my book taught me was right.

Comment: @user3657449: Which book, please?

Comment: @KerrekSB Introduction to Programming with C++ (2nd Edition). It was used in one of the examples.

Comment: Ouch. Treat the book with suspicion from here on in.

Comment: @user4581301 I will thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read the word like this:

```
while (fin >> word1 >> word2)
    cout << word1 << endl << word2 << endl;
```

Comment: Save a bit of code and a redundant flush: `cout << word1 << '\n' << word2 << endl;`